# Teacher appreciation week

Tags: daycare, teacher, presents

My 1.5 year old attends a private day-care/Montessori school. This is teacher appreciation week, and I am at a loss as to what to do to express my thanks. Since this is a day-care setting, even though there is one main guide for the room she is in, almost all other staff assist. So I feel odd to single out one or two guides for whatever we do.

I am terribly bad with artsy kind of things, so do not want to make cards for the teachers. Also, there's only one day to do something.

I can get some gift cards, but there are at least 5-6 people who take care of her at various points, so gets kind of expensive. Maybe I can get $10 gift cards for the 6 people, but I still feel odd that I am not giving anything to the other teachers.

Any other ideas?

Comment: You don't need to make anything -- volunteer some time, or to go on a trip. You can take a minute and write a note to all the staff telling them how much they are appreciated. As a former teacher, I would have been thrilled with either choice.

Answer (score 4):

Bring them something that they can share rather than individual presents.

Maybe you can bring them lunch or send cupcakes or chocolates or coffee.

Alternately, find out if there's something that the classroom really needs that they would benefit from. Teachers have a bad habit of spending their own money to enrich the school so saving them from that by finding out that the classroom really needs a new ____ might help.

At my son's school (also a small Montessori) they're celebrating all week by having parents sign up for potluck lunch/snacks. I think this is a really great idea. Maybe you can see if any of the other parents want to go in with you on something like this for tomorrow? You might check with the head of school to see if any of the teachers are vegetarian or have other dietary restrictions.

In future, it's always a great idea to talk with your other parents ahead of special times like this to see if they want to pool funds and then you can break that up among all of the teachers... so instead of you giving them each a $5 gift certificate, as a group the parents can give them each a $30 gift certificate (of course, depending on how much people can afford to give).

Comment: My classroom averaged 6-10 students, 2 teachers, 3-5 educational assistants (depending on the needs of the students in any given year). The first thing I did at the start of the year was request no personal gifts. We always had a list of things we wanted or needed that were out of budget and in our monthly newsletters, they were listed. (Everything from old newspapers, to painting shirts, to snack items). We were special needs in an elementary school and my teen wants gift cards which I think is too much. I liked this answer.